# How to run BatchNorm on a ragged tensor in TF 2.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to run BatchNormalization on a batch of ragged tensors in TF 2.x, but seem to run into errors while doing this. (I can do a conversion to and from ragged tensors before and after the BatchNorm forward call, but I'm unable to run a to_tensor() in NonEager mode, which is a requisite for me to train the network efficiently).

Pytorch has a BatchNorm1D, but TF does not seem to have any such API, any suggestions/pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a custom layer on keras just to convert your ragged tensor to tensor and then you inject that in the BatchNormalization Layer.

I actually tried that. Here is what I did and there is an issue but I did not have time to fix it. It might help you but perhaps not.

In the code below, I'm creating a super simple "to_tensor" layer that I could use before normalization.

It sort of work but since i'm creating a new tensor in the to.tensor() line, tf can't find any trainable variables anymore.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import *

def to_tensor(x):
    return x.to_tensor(shape=(None, 4))

X = tf.ragged.constant(
    [[3, 1, 4, 1], [], [5, 9, 2], [],[6]])

y = tf.random.normal(shape=(5,1))

inp = Input(shape=(None,), ragged=True)
x = Lambda(to_tensor)(inp)
out = Dense(1)(x)

m = Model(inp,out)

m.compile(optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
history = m.fit(X, y, epochs=10)
```

Comment: I tried using a similar variant in Eager mode, it did work. Does this work in non-eager mode?

Comment: Thank you for this, I'll try this out again and get back soon.

So if I understood this correctly, the main trick is to wrap to_tensor() in a keras layer as opposed to calling it directly on x inside the forward call?

Comment: that is one way, however, how are you gonna overcome the issue by using a to_tensor() which breaks the path your your trainable variables?

Comment: Exactly, my thoughts :( . I plan to have multiple such layers across the network, I don't know how to pass the gradient here.

Comment: ValueError: ('Input has undefined `axis` dimension. Input shape: ', TensorShape([None, None, None]))

this is what I get when I use BatchNormalization(x) instead of Dense in your example.